# There's something wrong with my topology, but I'm not sure what

Tags: mesh, topology

I am working on chair design for my portfolio. And there's like this tearing or jagged edge where the side of my mesh meets the top. Any assistance/ advice would be appreciated.

This is the image in edit mode. Note the front area, that's curving
[image: This is the image in edit mode. Note the front area, that's curving]

In this image it's in object mode. The area looks kinda sharp, but it's only in this small area
[image: In this image it's in object mode. The area looks kinda sharp, but it's only in this small area]

Comment: hello, please share your object so that we can check (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks for the grammatical edits, and for reaching out. Below is the URL to the modelhttps://pasteall.org/blend/56ca9f49736e433aa3ef56b7792ede26

Answer (score 2):

Try **recalculating normals** (SHIFT N) and also **merge by distance**. If it didn't solve it, inspect your mesh in x-ray mode to see if there's extra faces **inside** the mesh.